# Unable to change login credentials for Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login

I am using Stack Overflow using my work email. In the future, if I change work to a different company, I won't be able to access this account.

How can I change the Stack Overflow email to my personal email?

Comment: Doesn't changing your email [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/7155497) do that?

Comment: @George Thank you sir.. I had changed my credential.. A big salute  to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add another login to your account and then when you change jobs delete the old one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ivarni.. Now I am able to login my StackOverFlow account with both email id.. I would be no longer to open My Account when My email id will be deactivated by admin.